# Usage of Stream more than once

Tags: c#, stream, clone, filestream

I am trying to upload an image file to a repository using **HttpPostedFile.InputStream** and resize to different thumbnail sizes using the same stream.

- Step 1. Using **Stream sm = HttpPostedFile.InputStream** I am able to
  upload the file successfully.
- Step 2. Use the same stream to resize the image to different sizes.
  But always I get **error** saying that stream is being used.

Suppose if I skip step 1 and perform only step 2, I am able to resize the inputstream (images) to different size. Basically it is letting me to use the inputStream only once.

How can I achieve to process both step 1 and 2 sequentially ?

***I did try storing the inputStream to a variable and used separate copy for each step but no luck.***

Can someone suggest/help me ?

Thank you very much

Comment: an isolated code snippet showing the problem may help

Answer (score 5):

You did set Stream.Position to 0 before reusing it?

By storing in multiple variables you're probably only duplicating the reference to the same object in memory.

Comment: Thekip, I didn't set any **stream.position** to 0 before reusing. How can I do that?

Comment: after using it for the first time reset the stream (Position is a property on the stream).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this stream to upload several different images to a server, you probably want to open a new stream for each file you're uploading, rather than trying to upload all of them with a single stream.

Comment: Jason, I am using one stream to upload each file. After uploading when I use **same stream** to resize the images it is erroring.

Comment: @ajay. The best approach is to load the data into an Image object first. Then you can use the Image multiple times, to generate lots of thumbnails (there is a specific Image method to do this for you), and to save it to the upload stream. Trying to read the image multiple times from the same stream will be inefficient at best, and may not work at all.